# LocalNotification for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am implementing `local notifications` in my iOS app. Actually, I have a implementation with a method when i have created a notification :

```
-(void)setAlarmAction: (NSDate *) notificationDay days: (NSNumber *) day alert :  (NSNumber * ) priority  name:(NSString * ) nameNotification {

 NSDate *notificationDate = notificationDay;

 UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
 if (localNotification == nil) {
    return;
 }

 localNotification.fireDate = notificationDate;
 localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

 localNotification.alertBody =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Quedan %@ dias" , day];
 localNotification.alertAction = @"Ver Documento";

 localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
 localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]applicationIconBadgeNumber]+1; //aumenta en uno el numero de notificaciones

////////////
 NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"notification" forKey:nameNotification]; //1º que se guarda , 2º con que clave
 localNotification.userInfo = infoDictionary;
////////////
 NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:localNotification];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:nameNotification];

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

 // Get list of local notifications
 NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];

 for( UILocalNotification * local  in localNotifications) {

    NSLog(@"Notificacion: %@ fecha :%@",local.alertBody,local.fireDate.description);
 }

}

-(void) launchNotificacion:(Documento *)document  {

  self.txDate.text = document.text;

}
```

I want the app **run in background** and when it appear on the tabBar, i can push it and it go me to a concret view and launch a few data. I did it in the `didFinishlaunchingWithOptions`.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

 //self.viewDocumentForm
 VTDocumentFormViewController *VTDocument = [[VTDocumentFormViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VTDocumentFormViewController" bundle:nil];

 UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:
                                     UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

 if (notification) {

   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController: VTDocument animated:YES completion:nil];

   Documento *reminderDocument = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Documento" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
   reminderDocument = [notification.userInfo objectForKey: key ];

    [self.viewDocumentForm launchNotificacion:reminderDocument]; 
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber-1;
 }

// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;

}
```

But it doesn't work and i don't know the reason. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

`didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` in *launchOptions* will be invoked only if app was suspended/killed before *localNotification.fireDate* reached.

If you'r app is just in background (not killed) or active you'll got 
`application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` fired

Also i don't see in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` where did you register user notification settings (for iOS8)… smth like:

```
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;

    UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
}
```